# Different column size on each row (Grid)

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I am using CSS Grid in my layout...
How do I set different column size on first row and full width on second row?
Is this possible?
[image]

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not possible, the idea of css grid is to have a "grid", that is all the rows follow the same column configuration.

What you can do however is have an element span several column, and here you have several options:

This one stretches from the first column to the first from the end

```css
div:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

This one spans 2 columns from the first one:

```css
div:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Stephane! I don't know what happened to my previous comment but what I said was "Amazing! This is what I need. Thank you so much!!"